# Make JFreeChart CategoryPlot look like Flot.js bar chart

Tags: java, pdf, itext, jfreechart, flot

## Overview

I've been trying to mimic the [`flot.js`](http://www.flotcharts.org/) chart shown below in JFreeCharts.

[image]

so far I have succeeded in most elements such as individual bar colors with transparency, x and y grid lines and the background.

[image]

What I need to implement now are:

- the individual bar border colors
- solid black chart outline
- highest y-axis value pushed to chart's top

## What I've accomplished so far

### Individual bar border colors

For the individual bar border colors, I found the thread "[*Adding border color/stroke to individual Bars in Bar Chart?*](http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=29223)" that suggested to use the code

```
Color borderColor = buildColorMap.get(build);
renderer.setDrawBarOutline(true);
renderer.setSeriesOutlinePaint(iterator, borderColor);
```

as opposed to the one I currently use which is for all bars

```
// other colors
renderer.setSeriesOutlinePaint(3, new Color(213, 94, 0));
renderer.setSeriesOutlinePaint(4, new Color(204, 121, 167));
renderer.setSeriesOutlineStroke(0, new BasicStroke(2.5f));
```

### Chart outline

For the large outline for the chart, I saw [`setOutlineStroke`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/AbstractRenderer.html#setOutlineStroke(java.awt.Stroke)) but the API said

> Deprecated. This method should no longer be used (as of version 1.0.6). It is sufficient to rely on `setSeriesOutlineStroke(int, Stroke)` and `setBaseOutlineStroke(Stroke)`.
>   Sets the outline stroke for ALL series and sends a `RendererChangeEvent` to all registered listeners.

Hence I went to [`setBaseOutlineStroke`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/AbstractRenderer.html#setBaseOutlineStroke(java.awt.Stroke)) and nothing happened (still the same as the photo above)!

```
renderer.setBaseOutlineStroke(new BasicStroke(2.5f), true);
```

### `flot.js`-like y-axis handling and positioning

For the y-axis numbering in `flot.js`, I was able to mimic its behavior of selecting the highest y-value's ten's ceiling as the upper limit of the chart using the functions (wherein the data are placed in a `double` array; there are only five instances so I do not need a more complex data structure):

```
private static double getHighestArrayValue(double[] array) {
    double max = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] > max) {
            max = array[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
}

private static double getRoundedUpMultipleOfTen(double number) {
    return ((number + 9) / 10) * 10;
}
```

Wherein its usage to be the chart generated is:

```
CategoryPlot plot = ...

final NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
rangeAxis.setStandardTickUnits(NumberAxis.createIntegerTickUnits());
rangeAxis.setRange(0, 
   getRoundedUpMultipleOfTen(getHighestArrayValue(dataValues)));
rangeAxis.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(10));
```

resulting to

[image]

The problem now is how to push `50` to the top of the chart which I have no idea how to do.

---

Here is my full code for anyone interested (modified code of Viral Patel in "[*Generate Pie Chart/Bar Graph In PDF Using IText & JFreeChart*](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/generate-pie-chart-bar-graph-in-pdf-using-itext-jfreechart/)":

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Paint;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.StandardChartTheme;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberTickUnit;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.CategoryPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.BarRenderer;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.CategoryItemRenderer;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.StandardBarPainter;
import org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.Font;
import com.itextpdf.text.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfTemplate;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class ChartDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        writeChartToPDF(generateBarChart(), 800, 500, "D://barchart.pdf");
    }

    public static void writeChartToPDF(JFreeChart chart, int width, int height,
            String fileName) {
        PdfWriter writer = null;
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

        try {
            writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(
                    fileName));
            document.open();
            PdfContentByte contentByte = writer.getDirectContent();

            PdfTemplate template = contentByte.createTemplate(width, height);
            Graphics2D graphics2d = template.createGraphics(width, height);
            // controls size of image
            Rectangle2D rectangle2d = new Rectangle2D.Double(10, -10, width,
                    height);

            chart.draw(graphics2d, rectangle2d);

            graphics2d.dispose();
            contentByte.addTemplate(template, 0, 0);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        document.close();
    }

    static class CustomRenderer extends BarRenderer {

        private Paint[] colors;

        int transparency = 95;

        // http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Colors_(ggplot2)/
        public CustomRenderer() {
            this.colors = new Paint[] { new Color(1, 158, 115, transparency),
                    new Color(240, 228, 66, transparency),
                    new Color(0, 114, 178, transparency),
                    new Color(213, 94, 0, transparency),
                    new Color(204, 121, 167, transparency) };
        }

        public Paint getItemPaint(final int row, final int column) {
            return this.colors[column % this.colors.length];
        }
    }

    public static JFreeChart generateBarChart() {

        double[] dataValues = { 40.66, 37.82, 43.16, 32.62, 41.39 };
        Paint[] colors = { new Color(1, 158, 115), new Color(240, 228, 66),
                new Color(0, 114, 178), new Color(213, 94, 0),
                new Color(204, 121, 167) };

        DefaultCategoryDataset dataSet = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
        for (int i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
            dataSet.setValue(dataValues[i], "Population", (i + 1) * 2 + "");
        }

        ChartFactory.setChartTheme(StandardChartTheme.createLegacyTheme());
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart("", "Team number",
                "Solved problems (%)", dataSet, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
                false, true, false);
        chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);

        final CategoryPlot plot = chart.getCategoryPlot();
        ((BarRenderer) plot.getRenderer())
                .setBarPainter(new StandardBarPainter());

        plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);

        plot.setDomainGridlinesVisible(true);
        plot.setRangeGridlinesVisible(true);

        plot.setDomainGridlineStroke(new BasicStroke(0.25f));
        plot.setRangeGridlineStroke(new BasicStroke(0.25f));

        plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(new Color(204, 204, 204));
        plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(new Color(204, 204, 204));

        java.awt.Font fontGraphLabel = new java.awt.Font("Helvetica",
                Font.NORMAL, 12);
        java.awt.Font fontGraphTicks = new java.awt.Font("Helvetica",
                Font.NORMAL, 10);
        plot.getDomainAxis().setLabelFont(fontGraphLabel);
        plot.getRangeAxis().setLabelFont(fontGraphLabel);
        plot.getDomainAxis().setTickLabelFont(fontGraphTicks);
        plot.getRangeAxis().setTickLabelFont(fontGraphTicks);

        CategoryItemRenderer renderer = new CustomRenderer();
        plot.setRenderer(renderer);

        final NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
        rangeAxis.setStandardTickUnits(NumberAxis.createIntegerTickUnits());
        rangeAxis.setRange(0,
                getRoundedUpMultipleOfTen(getHighestArrayValue(dataValues)));
        rangeAxis.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(10));

        final BarRenderer renderer1 = (BarRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
        renderer1.setDrawBarOutline(true);
        renderer1.setShadowVisible(false);

        renderer1.setSeriesOutlinePaint(0, new Color(204, 121, 167));
        renderer1.setSeriesOutlinePaint(1, new Color(213, 94, 0));
        renderer1.setSeriesOutlineStroke(0, new BasicStroke(2.5f));

        renderer1.setBaseOutlineStroke(new BasicStroke(10f), true);

        return chart;
    }

    private static double getHighestArrayValue(double[] array) {
        double max = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] > max) {
                max = array[i];
            }
        }
        return max;
    }

    private static double getRoundedUpMultipleOfTen(double number) {
        return ((number + 9) / 10) * 10;
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm just curious: why aren't you using Flot?

Comment: I'm actually using both Flot and JFreeChart. I have a requirement to generate a PDF report with a graph that has a close resemblance to the one implemented in the web :)

Comment: So you are replicating the plot to JFreeChart just to generate a PDF?  Sounds to me like you are asking the wrong question.  And making maintenance of the application a pain.

Comment: @Mark, yes but with other details of the report. Do you mind sharing what should I do with this (re application maintenance)? I don't know how to put the flot.js chart in my PDF

Comment: For an application I work on we use flot in both the web and on the PDF reports.  To get it on the report, we generate the flot html/js and send it through phantomjs (http://phantomjs.org/), outputting a png of each plot.  This png is when included into the PDF.

Comment: @Mark, thank you, looks really convenient. I'll try it now :D

Comment: @Mark, do you know about any resources that show how to integrate PhantomJS into a Spring MVC webapp? I'm lost how to use it in my application.

Comment: I don't know anything about Spring MVC (or even Java reall), but see answer below, it's a barebones example of calling `phantomjs` to generate a PNG of a flot graph.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a Java guy but I'll give it a go with how I do it (all code untested)...

Say you have flot code that looks like this:

```
<div id="placeholder" style="width:300px;height:200px"></div>

$(function() {
    var series = {data: [[0, 5.2], [1, 3], [2, 9.2], [3, 10]],
                  lines: {show: false},
                  bars: {show: true, barWidth: 0.75, align:'center'}}

    somePlot = $.plot("#placeholder", [ series ], {});    
});
```

You need this code as a string, and then Base64 encode it (in a variable base64FlotCode).

Create a phantomJS script (saved as phantomJSScript.js) that looks like this:

```
var system = require('system');    
var html = system.args[1];    
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.onLoadFinished = function(status) {
    var clipRect = page.evaluate(
        function()
        { 
            var el = document.querySelector('#placeholder');
            return el.getBoundingClientRect();
        }
    );

    page.clipRect = {
        top:    clipRect.top,
        left:   clipRect.left,
        width:  clipRect.width,
        height: clipRect.height
    };
    page.render('/path/to/myPlot.png');

    phantom.exit();
};

function b64_to_utf8(str) {
    return decodeURIComponent(escape(window.atob(str)));
}

page.content = b64_to_utf8(html);
```

Now you can call this script as:

```
List<String> args = new ArrayList<String>();
args.add ("/path/to/phamtomjs.exe");
args.add ("/path/to/phantomJSScript.js");
args.add (base64FlotCode);
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder (args);
Process p = pb.start();
p.waitFor();
```

**EDITS**

Instead of passing phantomJS a string of your flot code, you could also point it to your webpage:

```
var system = require('system');      
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open('http://www.mywebpage.com', function() {
    var clipRect = page.evaluate(
        function()
        { 
            var el = document.querySelector('#placeholder');
            return el.getBoundingClientRect();
        }
    );

    page.clipRect = {
        top:    clipRect.top,
        left:   clipRect.left,
        width:  clipRect.width,
        height: clipRect.height
    };
    page.render('/path/to/myPlot.png');

    phantom.exit();
};
```

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate it. I'll try it now and update you asap

Comment: Do you know how I can get `base64FlotCode`?

Comment: @PASTRY, another idea, instead of passing the flot code string to phantomJS, you could point it back at your webpage.  See updates above.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try the new one again.

Comment: I do not get an output file. Do you know how `phantomjs.exe` parses the `List<String>` file path arguments? I want to make sure the exe and js files are read to check :(

Comment: Another thing, whenever I try to run the code, it is always stuck during `process.waitFor()`, I left it for 10 minutes and it still not stopping.